# sorting a nested dictionary by 3 criteria

Tags: python, sorting

I have a nested dictionary and I want to sort it by 3 fields, firstly by points secondly by wins(if points are equal) and lastly by alphabet if both points and wins are equal.

My dictionary:

```py
{'Iran': {'draws': 1,
          'goal difference': 0,
          'loses': 1,
          'points': 4,
          'wins': 1},
 'Morocco': {'draws': 1,
             'goal difference': 0,
             'loses': 1,
             'points': 4,
             'wins': 1},
 'Portugal': {'draws': 1,
              'goal difference': 0,
              'loses': 1,
              'points': 4,
              'wins': 1},
 'Spain': {'draws': 1,
           'goal difference': 0,
           'loses': 1,
           'points': 4,
           'wins': 1}}
```

My code:

```py
sort_data=sorted(dic.keys(),key=lambda x:(-dic[x]["points"],dic[x]["wins"]))
for items in sort_data:
    x=dic[items]
    print(items," ",str(x).replace("'", "").replace("{","").replace("}", ""))
```

my code dose not work in this case and dose not sort it by alphabet when all the situations are equal.Could you help me?

Comment: Can you fix your `dic`? It is not valid, there are too many nested `{...}`, making it more like a `set` of `dict` (except for the first element), which would not be legal either.

Comment: Just add `x` itself as another tie-breaker in the tuple: `key=lambda x: (-dic[x]["points"], dic[x]["wins"], x)`

Comment: Why did you use `-dic[x]['points']` and not `dic[x]['points']`? Why the minus sign? Are you sure you want to sort in reverse order of points?

Comment: @Stef, I think the OP wants the output to be in descending order like, they do in the FIFA world cup points table or Olympics medal table.

Comment: @SashSinha But in that case, shouldn't there also be a minus sign in front of `dic[x]["wins"]`? (I honestly don't know, I'm not familiar with FIFA world cup points tables).

Comment: Oh yeah, they should be. I added that in my answer but didn't realize OP didn't have that in theirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `dic.items()` rather than `dic.keys()`, although that's mostly a matter of taste.

```py
def sorted_dict(dic):
    def key(x):
        k,v = x
        return (v['points'], v['wins'], k)
    return dict(sorted(dic.items(), key=key))

dic1 = {'Iran': {'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 0, 'loses': 1, 'points': 4, 'wins': 1}, 'Morocco': {'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 0, 'loses': 1, 'points': 4, 'wins': 1}, 'Portugal': {'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 0, 'loses': 1, 'points': 4, 'wins': 1}, 'Spain': {'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 0, 'loses': 1, 'points': 4, 'wins': 1}}

dic2 = sorted_dict(dic1)

print(dic2)
# {'Iran': {'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 0, 'loses': 1, 'points': 4, 'wins': 1},
#  'Morocco': {'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 0, 'loses': 1, 'points': 4, 'wins': 1},
#  'Portugal': {'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 0, 'loses': 1, 'points': 4, 'wins': 1},
#  'Spain': {'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 0, 'loses': 1, 'points': 4, 'wins': 1}}
```

Note that in your dictionary, all countries have the same number of points and wins, and the countries are already sorted in alphabetical order, so this is a terrible example to test whether the sort worked correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dict.items` with a lambda instead:

```
import json  # For pretty printing only.

table = {
    'Iran': {
        'draws': 1,
        'goal difference': 0,
        'loses': 1,
        'points': 4,
        'wins': 1
    },
    'Morocco': {
        'draws': 1,
        'goal difference': 0,
        'loses': 1,
        'points': 4,
        'wins': 1
    },
    'Portugal': {
        'draws': 1,
        'goal difference': 0,
        'loses': 1,
        'points': 4,
        'wins': 1
    },
    'Spain': {
        'draws': 1,
        'goal difference': 0,
        'loses': 1,
        'points': 4,
        'wins': 1
    }
}

sorted_table = dict(
    sorted(table.items(),
           key=lambda kvp: (-kvp[1]['points'], -kvp[1]['wins'], kvp[0])))
print(json.dumps(sorted_table, indent=4))
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "Iran": {
        "draws": 1,
        "goal difference": 0,
        "loses": 1,
        "points": 4,
        "wins": 1
    },
    "Morocco": {
        "draws": 1,
        "goal difference": 0,
        "loses": 1,
        "points": 4,
        "wins": 1
    },
    "Portugal": {
        "draws": 1,
        "goal difference": 0,
        "loses": 1,
        "points": 4,
        "wins": 1
    },
    "Spain": {
        "draws": 1,
        "goal difference": 0,
        "loses": 1,
        "points": 4,
        "wins": 1
    }
}
```

***Note:** No change from input is because input is already sorted...*